# Testing a WCF Service Application

Tags: asp.net, wcf

How can you test a WCF Service Application like you could do with ASP.NET Web Services?  When I run the WCF Service Application, I would expect a test page to appear that would allow me to test all the services contained in the web application.  This does not happen.  Am I missing how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no web interface for testing your service. However, depending on which features your service are using you might be able to use the [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) included in the SDK. Unfortunately it has a lot of limitations so it wont work on all services.

From msdn:

> The following is a list of features not supported by WCF Test Client:
>
> Types: Stream, Message, XmlElement, XmlAttribute, XmlNode, types that implement the IXmlSerializable interface, including the related XmlSchemaProviderAttribute attribute, and the XDocument and XElement types, the ADO.NET DataTable type and the DataSet type (as well as its typed-derived classes).
>
> Duplex contract.
>
> Transaction.
>
> Security: CardSpace , Certificate, and Username/Password.
>
> Bindings: WSFederationbinding, any Context bindings and Https binding, WebHttpbinding (Json response message support).